# How do I make the image on the bottom go to the right side of the image on top in html or css?

Tags: html, css, image, margin, padding

My test website is https://lilio.000webhostapp.com/

I am trying to make the image on the **bottom** go to the **right** side of the image on the top. I have tried **margin** and **padding**

Below you can see my code. This is the intermediate result of how far I've come.:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>The Hot List</title>
        <style>
        #THL
        {
         font-family: Tahoma;
         font-weight: bold;
         color: #ffffff;   
        }

        #HB
        {
        width: 596px;
        background-color: #19AF52;
        padding: 0.1px;
        margin: -10px;
        margin-bottom: 26px;
        }

        #PGImg
        {
            margin-top: 8px;
        }

        #PGTitle
        {
            margin-top: 0px;
            padding: 0px;
            font-family: Tahoma;
            font-size: 11.50px;
            font-weight: bold;
        }

        #PGCreator
        {
            margin-top: -13px;
            padding: 0px;
            font-family: Tahoma;
            font-size: 8.75px;
            color: #19AF52;
        }

        #PGInfo
        {
            margin-top: -9px;
            padding: 0px;
            font-family: Tahoma;
            font-size: 8.50px;
            color: #c9c9c9;
        }

        </style>
    </head>
    <body>


    <!--Heading Bar-->
    <div id="HB">
        <h1 align="center" id="THL">The Hot List</h1>
    </div>

    <!--Programs-->
    <!--PG1-->
    <p></p>
    <img class="PG1" id="PGImg" 
         href="https://www.something.com/123" 
         src="https://www.something.com/123.png" alt="Program 1 Image" 
         height="130" width="130" 
         style="border-color:#c9c9c9;" border="1px">

    <!--PG1 Title-->
    <p id="PGTitle">Hard Working (UPDA...</p>
    <p id="PGCreator">CodingChamp01</p>
    <p id="PGInfo">109 Votes · 49 Spin-Offs</p>

    <!--PG2-->
    <p></p>
    <img class="PG2" id="PGImg"
         href="https://www.something.com/123" 
         src="https://www.something.com/123.png" alt="Program 1 Image" 
         height="130" width="130" 
         style="border-color:#c9c9c9;" border="1px">

    <!--PG2 Title-->
    <p id="PGTitle">Hard Working (UPDA...</p>
    <p id="PGCreator">CodingChamp01</p>
    <p id="PGInfo">109 Votes · 49 Spin-Offs</p>

    </body>
</html>
```

I hope you can help me with this, I would be very happy about it.

Answer (score 0):

You are using duplicate IDs, which won't work, and is [**invalid markup**](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/127178/two-html-elements-with-same-id-attribute-how-bad-is-it-really). You're already using classes for both images, so simply stick with those instead. I've removed the IDs for your images in my example, and the associated CSS selector. I've also removed the empty paragraphs between the two images, because you shouldn't be using empty paragraphs to control separation.

As for the actual problem, you don't just have two images you're dealing with; you have a lot of accompanying text as well. What I would recommend is creating `<div>` elements that surround each whole `PG` 'section'. I've given these new elements the classes `PG1_container` and `PG2_container` respectively.

Then simply `float` these containers to the `left`:

```
.PG1_container, .PG2_container {
  float: left;
}
```

This can be seen in the following example:

```css
#THL {
  font-family: Tahoma;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #ffffff;
}

#HB {
  width: 596px;
  background-color: #19AF52;
  padding: 0.1px;
  margin: -10px;
  margin-bottom: 26px;
}

#PGTitle {
  margin-top: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  font-family: Tahoma;
  font-size: 11.50px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

#PGCreator {
  margin-top: -13px;
  padding: 0px;
  font-family: Tahoma;
  font-size: 8.75px;
  color: #19AF52;
}

#PGInfo {
  margin-top: -9px;
  padding: 0px;
  font-family: Tahoma;
  font-size: 8.50px;
  color: #c9c9c9;
}

.PG1_container, .PG2_container {
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <!--Heading Bar-->
  <div id="HB">
    <h1 align="center" id="THL">The Hot List</h1>
  </div>
  <!--Programs-->
 
   <!--PG1-->
  <div class="PG1_container">
    <img class="PG1" href="https://www.khanacademy.org/computer-
programming/hard-working-updated-again/5565885026336768" src="https://www.khanacademy.org/computer-programming/hard-working-updated-
again/5565885026336768/5685265389584384.png" alt="Program 1 Image" height="130" width="130" style="border-color:#c9c9c9;" border="1px">
    <!--PG1 Title-->
    <p id="PGTitle">Hard Working (UPDA...</p>
    <p id="PGCreator">CodingChamp01</p>
    <p id="PGInfo">109 Votes · 49 Spin-Offs</p>
  </div>
  
  <!--PG2-->
  <div class="PG2_container">
    <img class="PG2" href="https://www.khanacademy.org/computer-
programming/hard-working-updated-again/5565885026336768" src="https://www.khanacademy.org/computer-programming/hard-working-updated-
again/5565885026336768/5685265389584384.png" alt="Program 1 Image" height="130" width="130" style="border-color:#c9c9c9;" border="1px">
    <!--PG2 Title-->
    <p id="PGTitle">Hard Working (UPDA...</p>
    <p id="PGCreator">CodingChamp01</p>
    <p id="PGInfo">109 Votes · 49 Spin-Offs</p>
  </div>
  
</body>
```

Hope this helps! :)